# iOS Custom Keyboard - General advice needed

Tags: ios, swift, keyboard

I am thinking of developing a custom keyboard where each key has three distinct button actions:

1. Single tap
2. Double tap
3. Long press

1 and 2 are for directly inputting common characters while 3 will be for a pop menu to select input for less common characters.

I've used `UIButton` `touchUpInside` event for single tap and `UITapGestureRecognizer` for double tap. I can somewhat make it work as separate events on a single button in the Main Storyboard, but it was kind of wonky on the Keyboard Storyboard for the Keyboard View Controller. Double tap on the button doesn't do anything.

Any advice appreciated.

Comment: i think help this link => https://www.appcoda.com/custom-keyboard-tutorial/

Comment: know about extension?

Comment: that link is more for programatical approach. I am just starting out, so I am using Storyboard. Quite new, so maybe you can give some direction for extensions.